# How do make a dynamic array thread-safe?

Tags: arrays, multithreading

Many times it's recommended to store objects in an array instead of keeping pointers to it everywhere in memory, for a number of reasons. On reason is less memory fragmentation by keeping everything contiguously. The other reason is better cache locality in accessing those objects (iterating, etc.).

But the problem I'm having is that any access to that array from more than one thread has to be synchronised because that array can be moved to another memory location. How are you supposed handle this without synchronising every single read/access? I don't want to lock a mutex or do a spin lock every time I read idx [] value in the array, especially since resizing and moving the contents of the array is going to happen only rarely. Is there a way to deal with this?

I'm using c++ and using a resizable array, something like an std::vector, but my own container that works pretty much the same.

Comment: Storing data contiguously is generally a good idea, but not really if many threads access to it because of *false sharing*. In this case, you need padding to avoid this effect. If each thread accesses cells locally, then thread-local arrays are better.

Comment: There are not al lot of way to synchronize things (at low level). Basically, atomics, mutex, semaphores and barriers do most of the job. Cooperative operations is another way to ensure synchronization but they generally need a point-to-point synchronization anyway. If your array can be resized, then a mutex is almost mandatory (atomics might be used but the probability to introduce a bug like an ABA problem is huge, and performance will certainly be not much better anyway). Read-write locks seems to be the best solution here. One can certainly even prove this if you provide a MRE.

Comment: Besides, please specify the language. Not all languages provide the same synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: @JérômeRichard You can't do something like pause all other threads when moving the container contents? Because if there were a way to do that then that would solve it.

Comment: Pausing thread is similar to what a mutex does except a mutex do not pause thread that are not waiting for the mutex to be locked by them. Besides, pausing each thread is more expensive and this require the pause to be precise. On top of that, you will need either to mark shared variable volatile (disabling many optimizations on them) or to put memory barrier (this is required to avoid undefined behaviours). All of that will be rather complicated (and a bit OS-dependent), while using a mutex is much simpler, faster, and portable.

Comment: Note that, depending of what you are doing in threads, [fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)) could help (more generally *cooperative* multitasking). In this case, you need to design a code so shared accesses is not even possible.